# What is the range of values a float can have in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point

What are its smallest and biggest values in python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477283/what-is-the-maximum-float-in-python

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See this [post](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/fa7a761411ced62b?pli=1).

Relevant parts of the post:

```
In [2]: import kinds 
In [3]: kinds.default_float_kind.M 
kinds.default_float_kind.MAX         kinds.default_float_kind.MIN 
kinds.default_float_kind.MAX_10_EXP  kinds.default_float_kind.MIN_10_EXP 
kinds.default_float_kind.MAX_EXP     kinds.default_float_kind.MIN_EXP 
In [3]: kinds.default_float_kind.MIN 
Out[3]: 2.2250738585072014e-308
```

Comment: Note that Numeric has been largely superseded  by NumPy. I wonder if a more modern equivalent of the kinds modules exists, though…

Answer (score 97):

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308,
 min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15,
 mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.2204460492503131e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

The smallest is `sys.float_info.min` (2.2250738585072014e-308) and the biggest is `sys.float_info.max` (1.7976931348623157e+308). See [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) for other properties.

`sys.float_info.min` is the normalized min. You can usually get the denormalized min as `sys.float_info.min * sys.float_info.epsilon`. Note that such numbers are represented with a loss of precision.  As expected, the denormalized min is less than the normalized min.

Comment: What is "normalized" min?

Comment: Normalized floating number starts with leftmost bit of mantissa set

Answer (score 9):

As a kind of theoretical complement to the previous answers, I would like to mention that the "magic" value ±308 comes directly from the binary representation of floats.  [Double precision floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) are of the form ±c*2**q with a "small" fractional value c (~1), and q an integer written with 11 binary digits (including 1 bit for its sign).  The fact that 2**(2**10-1) has 308 (decimal) digits explains the appearance of 10**±308 in the extreme float values.

Calculation in Python:

```
>>> print len(repr(2**(2**10-1)).rstrip('L'))
308
```

Answer (score 7):

Python uses double-precision floats, which can hold values from about 10 to the -308 to 10 to the 308 power.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format

Try this experiment from the Python prompt:

```
>>> 1e308
1e+308
>>> 1e309
inf
```

10 to the 309 power is an overflow, but 10 to the 308 is not.  QED.

Actually, you can probably get numbers smaller than 1e-308 via [denormals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number), but there is a significant performance hit to this.  I found that Python is able to handle `1e-324` but underflows on `1e-325` and returns `0.0` as the value.

Comment: And how's 1e+308 supposed to be bigger (see question) than infinity? ;)

Comment: @sfussenegger: The answer "-inf and +inf" is certainly a valid response to the question. Please post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 6):

Technically speaking, the smallest float is `-inf` and the max float `inf`:

```
>>> (float('-inf')            #   negative infinity 
< -1.7976931348623157e+308    #*  smallest float that is not negative infinity 
< -4.9406564584124654e-324    #*  biggest negative float that is not zero
< 0                           #   zero duh
< 4.9406564584124654e-324     #*  smallest positive float that is not zero
< 1.7976931348623157e+308     #*  biggest float that is not positive infinity
< float('inf'))               #   positive infinity
True
```

numbers with `*` are machine-dependent and implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 3):

Just playing around; here is an algorithmic method to find the minimum and maximum positive float, hopefully in any python implementation where `float("+inf")` is acceptable:

```
def find_float_limits():
    """Return a tuple of min, max positive numbers
    representable by the platform's float"""

    # first, make sure a float's a float
    if 1.0/10*10 == 10.0:
        raise RuntimeError("Your platform's floats aren't")

    minimum= maximum= 1.0
    infinity= float("+inf")

    # first find minimum
    last_minimum= 2*minimum
    while last_minimum > minimum > 0:
        last_minimum= minimum
        minimum*= 0.5

    # now find maximum
    operands= []
    while maximum < infinity:
        operands.append(maximum)
        try:
            maximum*= 2
        except OverflowError:
            break
    last_maximum= maximum= 0
    while operands and maximum < infinity:
        last_maximum= maximum
        maximum+= operands.pop()

    return last_minimum, last_maximum

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print (find_float_limits()) # python 2 and 3 friendly
```

In my case,

```
$ python so1835787.py
(4.9406564584124654e-324, 1.7976931348623157e+308)
```

so denormals are used.