# What is the maximum float in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, max, long-integer

The maximum integer in Python 2 is available by calling `sys.maxint`.

What is the maximum `float` or `long` in Python?

---

<sub>See also: [Maximum and Minimum values for ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966).</sub>

Comment: There is no `sys.maxint` in Python 3.

Answer (score 356):

For `float` have a look at [`sys.float_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, 
min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, 
epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

Specifically, `sys.float_info.max`:

```
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

If that's not big enough, there's always [positive infinity](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float):

```
>>> infinity = float("inf")
>>> infinity
inf
>>> infinity / 10000
inf
```

[`int` has unlimited precision](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric), so it's only limited by available memory.

Comment: actually, I found the sys.maxint is quite enough to my application

Comment: It seems `sys.float_info` is available starting from v2.6. How about v2.3-5?

Comment: Note sys.float_info.min is [defined](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) as "minimum positive **normalized** float". Smaller [denormal values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) are possible, down to `5e-324`

Comment: Cool, both are very useful. `inf` for all things python, and `float_info.max` as a workaround when the earlier doesn't work, for example `time.sleep(float("inf"))` is not allowed :(

Comment: @ladyfafa: sys.maxint is gone in Python 3, see also comments in the other answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795758/what-is-sys-maxint-in-python-3

Answer (score 18):

`sys.maxsize` (previously `sys.maxint`) is not the largest integer supported by python.  It's the largest integer supported by python's regular integer type.

Comment: +1 This is important. In Py3k, it's nearly meaningless -- it's the point at which Python (transparently!) changes the underlying datatype to `long`.

Comment: @katrielalex: `sys.maxint` isn't even defined in Python 3, it's called `sys.maxsize`, which is probably to be preferred in Python 2 as well.

Comment: @Scott Griffiths:  Not quite.  `sys.maxsize` (introduced in Python 2.6) and `sys.maxint` are two different things.  The first gives the maximum number of objects allowed in a collection (e.g., maximum size of a list, dict, etc.), and corresponds to a signed version of the C `size_t` type;  the second is the point after which the `int` type switches to `long`, and is the max value of a C `long`.  On some platforms the two values are different: e.g., on 64-bit Windows, `sys.maxsize` is `2**63-1` and `sys.maxint` is `2**31-1`.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson: Thanks for the correction - I hadn't realised they could ever be different (with 64-bit Python on Snow Leopard they are both `2**63-1`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795758/what-is-sys-maxint-in-python-3

Answer (score 10):

If you are using **numpy**, you can use **dtype** '*float128*' and get a max float of **10e+4931**

```
>>> np.finfo(np.float128)
finfo(resolution=1e-18, min=-1.18973149536e+4932, max=1.18973149536e+4932, dtype=float128)
```

Answer (score 3):

In python 3 there is no `sys.maxint`
There is a `sys.maxsize`

```
>>> sys.maxsize
2147483647
```

That *does not mean* that the maximum int is limited to 2 billion!
It means that the size of the object containing the integer has a maximum size of 2 billion bytes. I.e. a *very very large* number

For `float` have a look at `sys.float_info`

```
>>> sys.float_info
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

And specifically `sys.float_info.max`

```
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```