# whole float vs int OverflowError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Try type this in your Python 3.3.2 IDLE, hopefully I'm not the only one wondering and im willing to understand why this is happening.

```
>>> n = 331
>>> d = 165.0 # float number
>>> a = 174
>>> 
>>> a**d % n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    a**d % n
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

>>> d = int(d)
>>> a**d % n
330
```

How exactly the floats work and why is this happening? Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The largest possible float is about `1.7e308`. `174**165.0` is more than `1e330`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477283/maximum-float-in-python

Comment: I think the issue here is that Python integers have arbitrary precision, but floating point numbers don't.  So `int ** int` produces an `int`, but `int ** float` produces a `float`, but the number is too large to fit in a `float`, as Barmar points out.

Comment: It's worth noting that implementing `(x**y)%n` by actually computing `x**y`, then doing the `%` on it, is a bad idea in general. The intermediate values end up very large, which may mean overflowing your data type, losing precision (a `float` loses ones digits once you get past 2**53), and/or running much slower. And Python makes it easy to do things right: [`pow(x, y, n)`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#pow).

Comment: By the way, if this is part of a class assignment or a contest or something and you're not allowed to use `pow`, look up [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). If you just need to avoid overflow, repeated modular multiplication is sufficient; if you also use binary exponentiation, the result is usually faster to boot (although still not as fast as `pow`, at least in CPython, because it's using the same tricks, but coded in C).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `float` is an [IEEE 754 double-precision floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format), which means there's a maximum value it can hold (a bit over 10**308).*

An `int` is an arbitrary-precision integer, which grows as many bytes as are needed to hold any value, so it can't overflow.

This is described in the documentation under [Numeric Types - `int`, `float`, `complex`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric).

---

* Technically speaking, Python doesn't guarantee that it's an IEEE 754 double; it just says that it's usually a C `double`, and a C `double` is usually an IEEE 754 double… To see the actual limits on your platform, try `sys.float_info`.

Answer (score 4):

Your literal question was answered, but this is the answer you actually need ;-)

```
>>> pow(174, 165, 331)
330
```

Three-argument `pow()` is a **very** much more efficient way to do modular integer exponentiation.  Internally, intermediate results don't get much larger than 331**2, allowing for speedy computation of cases that otherwise wouldn't even fit in your computer's memory:

```
>>> pow(174, 16500000000000000, 331)
1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this example like this:

```
>>> 174 ** 165
4904852668653442061187838611454760487366325533178167907397373456352519588599065423233131397167737319275486886361329161677812258960306827407802115863260150459380820490013634069124303872650922835858611923329022540954288392236014102680789978826970589917040720077612506146107358709021927731368382330643430619926067887419695817233322447181310154127711515923344426608176922624
>>> 174 ** 165.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    174 ** 165.0
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

As you can see, it fails when you have a float as the exponent. To understand this, a look into the manual helps:

> Integers have unlimited precision. Floating point numbers are usually implemented using `double` in C […] ([source](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex))

So essentially, you can do whatever you want with integers; but floats are restricted to the standard [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) limits.