# Overflow Error: ..long int too large

Tags: python

```
import math
a = 100
b = 110
e = 2.71828
x = (e**-a)*(a**b)/math.factorial(b)
print round(x, 5)
```

when a and b are large I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float
```

Comment: `math.factorial(b)` == 198! == 1.98..e370 that's bigger than Double.MaxValue

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory: the value is too large

Comment: A better question might to ask why you need the factorial of 198!

Comment: this is Poisson distribution ,and i need that for numbers between 140 - 220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as (a**b) >> math.factorial(b) you could just do

```
(a**b)/math.factorial(b)*(e**-a)
```

this way the number gets smaller before being converted to float

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be trying to implement a Poisson distribution. For large values of its mean, it is very well approximated by a Gaussian distribution, for which you do not need to compute the factorial (which is way too big as others already said).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Related_distributions

Edit: the number of events k is independant of the mean, but usually one does not want a probability such as P(200|L) for small L, or one rounds it to zero.

Also have a look at Scipy's implementation, which seems to use the logarithm, another way or avoiding very large numbers:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/stats/_discrete_distns.py

**Edit**: since it was requested, a demo in R (because it is quicker for me in my current setup, but the maths are the same). I took lambda = mean = sigma^2 = 500 (without the continuity correction for n<1000):

```
pois = rpois(1000, 500)
norm = rnorm(1000, 500, sqrt(500))
plot(density(pois))
lines(density(norm))
```

[image]

Comment: How did you figure out the willings of the OP ?

Comment: The formula is easy to recognize. I had to approximate Binomial with Poisson for similar reasons. At some point even with Decimal you will reach the limits of your hardware.

Comment: yes this is Poisson, I dont know he was similar with Gaussian , thank you

Comment: It's old, but can you please add the code that demonstrates your suggestion?

Comment: @0x90 Maths don't become too old, and you will find the demonstration in math books. But I added a graphical example using simple R code.

Answer (score 1):

You are exceeding the max float value (`1.7976931348623157e+308`).

Use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/decimal.html) module:

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal   
a = 200
b = 198
e = 2.71828
x = Decimal(e**-a)*Decimal(a**b)/math.factorial(Decimal(b))
print round(x, 5)
```

Output:

```
0.02806
```

Compare it with the output that [WloframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(e%5E-200)*(200%5E198)%2F(198!)) calculated `0.0280567`

---

In case you want to see the float info, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477283/maximum-float-in-python):

```
>>> import sys
>>> print  sys.float_info
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

Comment: Interesting. This works for 198 but will fill you whole memory quickly as the number increases, or am I wrong?