# Python scope of numerical type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use python3.x,I want to know the scope of numerical type.

For example, the float, the maximum and the minimum.

I know the scope of java's float and int, but in python I can't find it now.

For example,java float from 10^-38 to 10^38,so python's float?

Comment: `Scope` does not mean what you think it means; the term you seem to be looking for is *range*.

Comment: Scope? Lexical. Length https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints#7604981

Comment: What do you mean "the scope of java's float"? max float number? amount of distinct float numbers?

Comment: for floats see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477283/what-is-the-maximum-float-in-python

Answer (score 0):

`int` and `float` are the names of built-in types and are always in scope in Python.  I don't know what you mean by "the maximum and the minimum" but `max` and `min` are built-in functions, thus always in scope.