# fixed point to find root of a²＋a³＝392 but report OverflowError

Tags: python-3.x, sicp

I tried to find the root of a²＋a³＝392 with fixed_point introduced by SICP [1.1.3 functions as general method](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%_sec_1.3.3)

```
#+BEGIN_SRC scheme :session sicp
(define tolerance 0.00001)

(define (fixed-point f first-guess)
  (define (close-enough? v1 v2)
    (< (abs (- v1 v2))
       tolerance))
  (define (try guess)
    (let ((next (f guess)))
      (if (close-enough? guess next)
          next
          (try next))))
  (try first-guess))
#+END_SRC
```

I rewrite it in python as:

```
#+begin_src ipython :session sicp :results output :tangle pySrc/sicp_fixedpoint.py
import math
tolerance = 0.00001

import math

def fixed_point(f, guess):
    while True:
        nex = f(guess)
        if abs(guess-nex) < tolerance:
            return nex
        else:
            guess = nex 

def f(x):
    return 392 / (x + x**2)
fixed_point(f, 1)
#+end_src
```

It report error:

```
 OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477283/what-is-the-maximum-float-in-python: by adding a print for the value of `x`, I get 1.861351852240379e+293 and `x**2` is >> than `sys.float_info`, that is, `1.7976931348623157e+308`.
Neither `decimal.Decimal` helps you, as it crashes at `x = 4.061798841378423761845858231E+600616`

Comment: `def f(x): return math.sqrt(392/(x+1))`

Comment: Given the original formula (@gboffi what is that function?), your nex and your guess will always be positive. In order to solve the specific problem , you have to solve `x-(392//x+x**2)( <= tolerance`. Given the value of `tolerance`, you accept all the values below 7 (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E3+%2B+x%5E2+-392+-+0.00001), but, since that value must be below the tolerance in its abs value, you also have https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+-x%5E3+-+x%5E2+%2B392+-+0.00001.  So, your solution is x=7.

Comment: @gboffi sorry can't see the point: it gets 19.30529743549647 as a solution, but does not solve the original problem.

Comment: thanks @gboffi. I am missing some math behind. I see it is converging to the solution but I do not know why.

Comment: @Algebra the expression `392 / (x + x**2)` either becomes zero after a couple of iterations (when doing integer division) or never converges (when doing floating-point division), so I suspect there's something wrong with your fixed point solution. What's the number of this exercise in SICP? you should always provide this info for SICP-related questions.

Comment: ty, I add the reference to question and thus cannot appreciate it  more for your patience on tutoring and thus  delighted to continue chapter 2 in scheme. @ÓscarLópez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem is not well suited for solving via a fixed-point procedure. If you print the `(abs (- next guess))` for each iteration, you'll see that the value is *increasing* between iterations, it'll never converge to the specified tolerance - hence the `Numerical result out of range` error.