# What is the longest possible string representation of a Python float?

Tags: python, floating-point, string-formatting

What is the maximum length of `str(float(any_possible_value))` in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum float in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477283/what-is-the-maximum-float-in-python)

Comment: If you are trying to format a table, you almost certainly want to pick a column width, and round the values to some fixed, but *smaller*, number of digits.

Comment: @azro. That's definitely not a duplicate

Comment: With exponential decimal notation, -d.ddddddddddddddd-eyyy (1+1+1+16+1+1+3 = 24) is sufficient to distinguish all values.  -1.797...e+308 needs 310 characters otherwise.   Small values near 0.0 need a few more.

Comment: I do not follow the Python specification closely, but, last I knew, it did not impose specific formats on floating-point, and I am not sure it imposes specific requirements on the results of `str` as applied to floating-point. E.g., one Python implementation might choose to show only as many digits are needed to uniquely distinguish a number from its neighboring floating-point values while another Python implementation might choose to show the exact value (requiring possibly hundreds of digits). If so, there is no maximum length determined by the Python specification.

Answer (score 1):

There is no maximum length since you can print as many digits as you choose. For example:

```
f'{0.1:.25g}'
```

It also depends on the format:

```
f'{1e-6:.6f}'  # 0.000001
```

vs

```
f'{1e-6:.6g}'  # 1e-06
```

Then of course there's locale, and probably other factors.

But you can still get a reasonable upper bound on what `str(float(x))` can reasonably return:

- There are 53 bits of mantissa precision in an IEEE 754 binary double precision float. That's about 15-16 decimal digits. 17 with the leading zero or one (e.g., `sys.float_info.max`  shows that many)
- One digit for the decimal point.
- Scientific notation will have `'e'`, a sign, and up to three decimal digits of exponent (bounded by the radix precision), for a total of five.
- There can be a sign character.

**24** characters seems like a reasonable upper bound for what `str(float(x))` might return in the default locale under normal circumstances.

Comment: You forgot the negative sign, the answer is 24. And also format strings have nothing to do with `str(float())` but I appreciate that you’re one of the first people to actually read the question

Comment: @Boris. I mentioned the formatting because internally, `str` has to choose some representation. I could look it up or make some educated hand wavy guesses. I chose the latter since it's less work :)

Comment: @Boris. I updated to 24. I missed a potential digit. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score -2):

You can get the max lenght of a float by running:

```
sys.float_info.max
```

It returns: `1.7976931348623157e+308`. A string is only limited to pythons ram, so thats the biggest number.

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: I would say that positive/negative is stored in one bit extra, so it would be `-(1.7976931348623157e+308)`, but i couldn't find info on that.

Comment: My question is about the string representation, not bits.