# OverflowError: int too large to convert to float - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math

i'm working on basic calculus and factorials with python. Trying to produce PI from newton series, but i cant go further than 171 iterations because of this error: OverflowError: int too large to convert to float. Here's the code:

i've imported this: from math import factorial, gamma / from math import sqrt

```
def calculus(ran):

    x = 1/2

    exp = 0
    p = 0

    terminos = []
    length = len(terminos)

    for i in range(ran):
        k = i
        n = 1/2

        tzero = 1

        exp += 2

        num = gamma(n)

        if k != 0:
           
            den1 = factorial(k)
            den2 = n-k
            den3 = gamma(den2)
            den = den1 * den3
            f1 = num/den

           
            f2 = 1/(exp+1)
            f3 = x**(exp+1)

            terminos.append(f1*f2*f3)
        else:
            f1 = x
            f2 = 1
            f3 = 1
            terminos.append(f1*f2*f3)

    p = 0

    terminos.append(-sqrt(3)/8)

    serie = sum(terminos)

    pi = serie * 12

    print(pi)

calculus(172)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477283/what-is-the-maximum-float-in-python the maximum float is about `1.7e308`, i.e. 308 decimal digits.

Comment: On my pc the result does not change past `calculus(22)`. Why do you need more iterations?

Comment: It does change in between larger iterations. Calculating Pi it's something of exactitud, so you need to go "bigger" for more of this exactitud.

Comment: @J04c0 But floats aren't exact... Maybe you want to use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) instead, which supports arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/index.html) in cases where precision is important it's better to use `decimal` or `fractions` modules.

For example, instead of writing `f2 = 1/(exp+1)` you should write

```
from fractions import Fraction
f2 = Fraction(1, exp+1)
```

Read [this article](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) to get a better understanding.

Note that doing such heavy computations is not recommended in Python itself even with built-in libraries like `fractions`. You should use libraries such as [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) for better performance and also better precision.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Would that solve my problem?

Comment: Using numpy will solve your problem and it's a good solution.

Comment: Thanks then, much appreciated!!