# Handling overflow and underflow conditions in Python decimal conversions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a Python function that takes a *float* number as input and converts it to a *decimal*, then to a *string*. However, I need to restrict the number of digits in the exponent of the *decimal* representation to two, while allowing any exponent for the *float* number. Consequently, any exponent *>= e+100* should be reduced to *e+99*, and any number with exponent *<= e-100* should be considered as 0. How can I achieve this in Python?

Currently, I'm struggling to catch when a number is *Overflow* or *Underflow*:

```
from decimal import (Clamped, Context, Decimal, Inexact, Overflow, Rounded, Underflow)
import math

def format_number(value):
    # Parameters
    MAX_EXPONENT = 99
    DYNAMODB_CONTEXT = Context(Emin=-99, Emax=99, prec=30, traps=[Clamped, Overflow, Underflow])

    try:
        number = str(DYNAMODB_CONTEXT.create_decimal(value))
        if number in ['-Infinity', 'Infinity', 'NaN']:
            print('Infinity and NaN not supported')
            return(false)
    except decimal.Overflow as e:
        print("Overflow")
        return(false)
    except decimal.Underflow as e:
        print("Underflow")
        return(false)
    print(number)
    return number

format_number(-1e-322)
format_number(1e-322)
format_number(-1e322)
format_number(1e322)
```

This code returns:

```
ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in format_number
decimal.Underflow: [<class 'decimal.Underflow'>, <class 'decimal.Clamped'>]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 14, in format_number
NameError: name 'decimal' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Decimal'?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of different problems you are facing.

##### 1. `except` clauses

Since you have already have imported `Overflow` and `Underflow`, you can just use them as `except Overflow as e:`. If you want to do it the way you have right now, you need to add `import decimal`.

##### 2. Booleans

Booleans need to be capitalized in python so `return false` -> `return False`. Also note that brackets are not needed with returns (even when having multiple returns).

##### 3. Infinity cases

With some of your test cases you are running to the [maximum float value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477283/what-is-the-maximum-float-in-python), so you might want to handle +/-inf with underflow/overflow. I tested with some more moderate exponents like 1e102 and it seemed to work as intended.