# Python epsilon is not the smallest number

Tags: python, python-2.7, epsilon

What does `sys.float_info.epsilon` return?

On my system I get:

```
>>> sys.float_info.epsilon
2.220446049250313e-16
>>> sys.float_info.epsilon / 2
1.1102230246251565e-16
>>> 0 < sys.float_info.epsilon / 2 < sys.float_info.epsilon
True
```

How is this possible?

**EDIT:**

You are all right, I thought epsilon does what min does. So I actually meant `sys.float_info.min`.

**EDIT2**

Everybody and especially John Kugelman, thanks for your answers!

Some playing around I did to clarify things to myself:

```
>>> float.hex(sys.float_info.epsilon)
'0x1.0000000000000p-52'
>>> float.hex(sys.float_info.min)
'0x1.0000000000000p-1022'
>>> float.hex(1 + a)
'0x1.0000000000001p+0'
>>> float.fromhex('0x0.0000000000001p+0') == sys.float_info.epsilon
True
>>> float.hex(sys.float_info.epsilon * sys.float_info.min)
'0x0.0000000000001p-1022'
```

So `epsilon * min` gives the number with the smallest positive significand (or mantissa) and the smallest exponent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`epsilon` is the difference between `1` and the next representable float. That's not the same as the smallest float, which would be the closest number to `0`, not `1`.

There are two smallest floats, depending on your criteria. `min` is the smallest [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number_%28computing%29) float. The smallest [subnormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) float is `min * epsilon`.

```
>>> sys.float_info.min
2.2250738585072014e-308
>>> sys.float_info.min * sys.float_info.epsilon
5e-324
```

Note the distinction between normalized and subnormal floats: `min` is not actually the smallest float, it's just the smallest one with full precision. Subnormal numbers cover the range between `0` and `min`, but they lose a lot of precision. Notice that `5e-324` has only one significant digit. Subnormals are also much slower to work with, up to 100x slower than normalized floats.

```
>>> (sys.float_info.min * sys.float_info.epsilon) / 2
0.0
>>> 4e-324
5e-324
>>> 5e-325
0.0
```

These tests confirm that `5e-324` truly is the smallest float. Dividing by two underflows to 0.

See also: [What is the range of values a float can have in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835787/what-is-the-range-of-values-a-float-can-have-in-python/1839009#1839009)

Comment: My example works the same way for sys.float_info.min instead of sys.float_info.epsilon everywhere. How do you explain this?

Comment: Anything smaller than `min` is subnormal. `min * epsilon` is the true smallest float. If you divide it by 2 it underflows to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You actually want `sys.float_info.min` ("minimum positive normalized float"), which on machine gives me `.2250738585072014e-308`.

`epsilon` is:

> difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1 that is representable as a float

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) for more info on the fields of `sys.float_info`.

Comment: `min` still isn't quite the smallest positive float; there are still subnormals below it.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, but how do you explain what @user2357112 said?

Comment: Subnormals floats mean the number has zeros in its significand; I think @John Kugelman has the better answer at this point: I'd accept that one if it works for you, otherwise I can update this one if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your last expression is possible, because for any real, positive number, `0 < num/2 < num`.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info):

> difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1 that is representable as a float

Answer (score 0):

sys.float_info is defined as

> difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1 that is
>   representable as a float

on [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) defines `sys.float_info.epsilon` as the

> difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1 that is representable as a float

However, the gap between successive floats is bigger for bigger floats, so the gap between `epsilon` and the next smaller float is a lot smaller than `epsilon`. In particular, the next smaller float is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Like every answer says, it's the difference between `1` and the next greatest value that can be represented, if you tried to add half of it to 1, you'll get 1 back

```
>>> (1 + (sys.float_info.epsilon/2)) == 1
True
```

Additionally if you try to add two thirds of it to `1`, you'll get the same value:

```
>>> (1 + sys.float_info.epsilon) == (1 + (sys.float_info.epsilon * (2./3)))
True
```