# Python uses the scientific notation to show that 5.26E-325 is 0,but 5.26E-324 is 5e-324,why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scientific-notation

I use this code to test scientific notation:

```
a = 5.26E-324
print(a)

a = 5.26E-325
print(a)
```

**The code result:**

```
5e-324
0.0
```

**Questions:**

1. Why `5.26E-325` cannot show `5e-325`?
2. Does this mean that less than `E-324` is shown to be `0.0`?
3. Is there a way to show `5e-325`?

Comment: There is a limit to how small (or big) a float can be. You just hit it. If you need more precision you may need to use float128...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the range of values a float can have in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835787/what-is-the-range-of-values-a-float-can-have-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the question if you represent `5.26E-325` in python: Yes, with the `decimal` module:

```
from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal("5e-324")
Decimal('5E-324')
>>> Decimal("5e-325")
Decimal('5E-325')
>>> Decimal("5e-100000")
Decimal('5E-100000')
>>> Decimal("5e-100000") + Decimal("5e-100000")
Decimal('1.0E-99999')
```

The decimal module has (after my knowledge) no limit in the exponents, but like the float in precision. But the precision shouldn't be a problem, because you can set is to a really high number.

The other question where answered in the post below quite good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.float_info` to check floatinfo settings of Python as `Akash Gupta` suggests.

However, it has not been changed from Py2.7 to Py3+ because the smallest representable denormalized float (larger than zero) can be calculated via `min representable` and `floating epsilon`.

Try this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
>>> sys.float_info.min * sys.float_info.epsilon
5e-324
```

And you will find that `5e-324` comes from `2.22e-308 * 2.22e-16`.

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably due to double precision factors,

Run these commands in your python console:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info
```

In python 2.7 it used to return:

```
sys.floatinfo(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308,
min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53,
epsilon=2.2204460492503131e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

It must have changed to the value you are trying in python 3.x

Hope this helps.

for more see [Python double precision examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Double-precision_examples)