# divide 2 probability extremely weak

Tags: python

i got probability extremely weak and i need divide 1 proba per 1 other probability.

Imagine it :

```
a=5e-150000
b=a=5e-150000
print(a/b)
```

the results must be 1  but python say me :

```
    print(a/b)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Do you have a solution to don't got this message error ?

Thanks for reading me !

Answer (score 3):

The floating-point type cannot represent such a value:

```
>>> 5e-150000
0.0
```

You can instead use the `Decimal` class from the standard library to represent numbers like that:

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal('5e-150000') * Decimal('2e149999') # evaluates to `Decimal(1.0)`
Decimal('5e-150000') / Decimal('5e-150000') # no problem here either
```

Comment: It could be noted that you can check if a number is too small for a float representation; if it's below the MIN value gotten via the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835787/what-is-the-range-of-values-a-float-can-have-in-python).